# stored proc from multiple select statements in Tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

-> I want to write a stored proc which outputs the columns from 2 select statements

->the columns from one select statement will be the inputs to the second select statement

```
create procedure sp_proc
@inputId int
As 
Begin 

Select t1.ticketId AS ticket, 
t2.name AS NAME,
t3.status AS STATUS, 
t2.id ID
from table1 t1
Inner JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.ticketId= t2.ticketId
INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t3.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.ticketId IS NOT NULL
AND t2.id = @inputId 


Select t1.ticketId, t2.name , D.desc, t2.id
from table1 t1
Inner JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.ticketId= t2.ticketId
INNER JOIN( SELECt TOP 1 from table4 t4 ORDER BY t4.date  where t4.ticketId = ticket)AS D
ON t4.ticketId = t2.ticketId
WHERE t4.ticketId =ticket
```

I want the `ticket, NAME,STATUS, ID , desc` when user supplies `@inputId` to proc

Comment: Your database structure and requirement is not clear .. What problem you are facing you have written multiple select statements and with inner query.

Comment: i had tried this by writing 2 select statements where first i will get the "ticketid" from first query associated to the user input, and then get the latest "desc" associated to this "tickectId" . the output of proc should be all rows(having colums of both queries) for a supplied inputId

Comment: no idea what version of SQL server you're using, but have you tried CTEs?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to combine everything in one query. It's my guessing, because you seem to miss something:

```
SELECT
  t1.ticketId AS ticket, 
  t2.name AS NAME,
  t3.status AS STATUS, 
  t2.id AS ID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 desc FROM table4 WHERE t1.ticketId=table4.ticketId ORDER BY DESC) AS DESC
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.ticketId= t2.ticketId
INNER JOIN table2 t4 ON  t1.ticketId= t4.ticketId
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.name = t2.name

WHERE t1.ticketId IS NOT NULL AND t2.id = @inputId
```

But I am not sure where are you trying to get here:

```
INNER JOIN( SELECt TOP 1 from table4 t4 ORDER BY t4.date  where t4.ticketId = ticket)AS desc
ON t4.ticketId = t2.ticketId
```

I'm guessing you are after latest something in table4 for given ticketId... so I made my query on this assumption.

Comment: in table4 Ihave multiple "description" entries for a ticketId, and im trying to get the latest "description" for the ticketId

Comment: Im not sure if my approach is correct but the whole intention of the proc is :
1) first i will get the "ticketid" from first query associated to the user input,
2) and then get the latest "desc" associated to this "tickectId" . 3) final output of proc should be all rows(having colums of both queries) for a supplied inputId

Comment: So basically you can do it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

An inline scalar query will work

```
create procedure sp_proc
@inputId int
As 

Select t1.ticketId AS ticket, 
t2.name AS NAME,
t3.status AS STATUS, 
t2.id ID,
[DESC] = (SELECT TOP(1) [DESC]
          from table4 t4
          where t4.ticketId = t1.ticketId
          ORDER BY t4.date)
from table1 t1
Inner JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.ticketId= t2.ticketId
INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t3.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.ticketId IS NOT NULL
AND t2.id = @inputId;
GO
```

Comment: this cant be done as i get bound error for the inner select statment

Comment: It only means that you are not applying it correctly. With the highly obfuscated table names, it's hard to tell where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve it with single query.

create procedure sp_proc
@inputId int
As

Select t1.ticketId AS ticket, 
t2.name AS NAME,
t3.status AS STATUS, 
t2.id ID,
t4Description.[desc]
from table1 t1

Inner JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.ticketId= t2.ticketId

INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t3.name = t2.name

OUTER APPLY (

```
              SELECT TOP 1 [desc]
              FROM table4 t4
              WHERE t4.ticketId = t1.ticketId
              ORDER BY t4.[date] DESC

        ) t4Description
```

WHERE
     t1.ticketId IS NOT NULL
     AND t2.id = @inputId